# other codes for this recursive function on list

Tags: list, haskell, fold

i wrote a function  to find the position of the next column of an asciibox
for instance :

```
+-----++---++---+
|  a  || b || c |
+-----++---++---+
```

box b should start at column  "pseudo code " {length (box a)} and box c should start at pseudo code {length box a + length box b}

so i wrote this function

```
f:: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]
f (x:xs) []  = f xs [x]
f  [] ys = ys
f (x:xs) ys = f xs (ys++[x+ last ys])
```

which gives me what i want

```
f [23,24,25] [] 
ghci> [23,47,72]
```

i would like to know if other algorithm is possible . Is there any solution with "fold" or "unfold" or perhaps "iterate"

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> scanl (+) 0 [23, 24, 25]
[0,23,47,72]
```

Comment: Or `scanl1 (+) [23, 24, 25]`, if the list is never empty, that gets rid of the 0.